# InsertionSort on Linked List , with Data from text file. Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I'm doing insertion sort with my Linked List, and I have faced an issue.

My Data file:

```
Myjob 66
Junk   17
Fun    25
Vital       99
Important   96
MoreFun    28
Work      69
Assignment  44
```

Here is my code for Insertion Sort

```
public Node insertSort(Node node){
   Node sortedNode = null;
   while(node != null){
    Node current = node;
    node = node.next;
    Node x;
    Node previous = null;
    for(x = sortedNode; x != null; x = x.next){
        if(current.getData().getNum() > x.getData().getNum()){
                break;
         }
         previous = x;
    }
    if(previous == null){               
          current.next = sortedNode;
          sortedNode = current;
    }
    else{               
       current.next = previous.next;
       previous.next = current;
    }
  }
   sortedNode=head;
  return sortedNode; }
```

My currently output:

```
Name = Myjob            Priority=66
Name = Assignment            Priority=44
Name = MoreFun            Priority=28
Name = Fun            Priority=25
Name = Junk            Priority=17
null
```

they skip whatever greater than 66. Do anyone have any ideas how to fix this issue, so it can display from 99 down to 17? I tried rearranging the order in the text file a little bit, with the highest first. then the program can perform sorting from 99 back to 17 perfectly. But with the original order, my program just can perform sorting from 66 to lowest. I don't know why, and how to fix it? Please help.  I'm very new in Java. Thank you so much.

My Data Class

```
public class Data {

private String name;
private int num;

public Data(){
}

public Data(String name,int num){
    this.name=name;
    this.num=num;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public int getNum(){
    return num;
}

public void setNume(int num){
    this.num=num;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Name = " + name + "            Priority=" + num ;
}

}
```

Here is my LinkedList Class:

```
public class LinkedList {
Node head;
Node prev;
Node cur;


public LinkedList(){

}

public LinkedList(Node head){
    head = null;
}

//getter to get head
public Node gethead(){
    return head;
}

public void printLinkedList(){
    System.out.println(head);
}

public void initializeLL(){
    Node currentNode = head;
    try
    {
        File file = new File("Asg2Data.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            Data d = new Data(sc.next(), sc.nextInt());
            Node n = new Node(d);

            if(currentNode == null){
                currentNode = n;
                head = n;
            }else{
                currentNode.setNext(n);
                currentNode = n;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
        l1.initializeLL();
        l1.insertSort(l1.head); 
        l1.printLinkedList();
        System.out.println("************");
}
}
```

Here is my Node Class:

```
public class Node{
Data dt;
Node next;

public Node(){

}
public Node(Data dt){
    this.dt=dt;
}


public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next){
    this.next=next;
}


public Data getData(){
    return dt;
}

public void setData(Data dt){
    this.dt=dt;
}


public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(dt).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
    sb.append(next).append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 

    return sb.toString();

}
}
```

The insertionSort method is inside the LinkedList Class.

Comment: seems like your issue happens when you need to add an item to the beginning of the list.

Comment: I found it too. But I have no idea how to fix my code. Can you help me ?

Comment: @nhouser9 I just added the rest of my codes.  Please take a look and help. Thanks so much.

Comment: What are you expecting your insertion sort to do? Sort the entire list? When I think of insertion sort I think of sorting each item as it is inserted, which is not what is happening here since you initialize the list from a file and then sort it.

Comment: @nhouser9 So how can I do to fix my code?  I'm stucking. I'm new in java. so I don't have much experiences about those sorting.  Can you show me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your code here is correct?
I trace your code and I find that for loop is not run anyway because x is always null in each run of insertSort() function.

How you call insertSort() function to sort data?

**EDIT**:

Ok. I review your code. I found that your sort is correct but after sorting function head of LinkList is not update. So your code prints sorted list from old head.
You should update head of linkedlist after sort function.

Comment: **Are you sure your code here is correct?** actually he is not, plus your response as an answer is interrogative and not solution-based in nature, try presenting a solution is all I mean

Comment: @hadi.mansouri I just added the rest of my code at the above. Please take a look and help. Thanks so much.

Comment: @ShayHaned I just added my code.  Please take a look and help . Thanks so much.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: @nhouser9 I have not permission to comment. I have not sufficient REPUTATION to comment. StackOverflow does not allow me to comment. :(

Comment: @Dustin Le I edit my comment. View it. I have not permission to comment on your post. So I asked my question on a comment. After that I edit my comment to answer you.

Comment: I add  sortedNode=head; at the end like above. but look like it's doesn't work. :( Do you have any idea how i can update head node ? @hadi.mansouri ?

Comment: @hadi.mansouri My program worked perfectly now. Thank you so much, brother.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here. Firstly you have some bugs in your code like returning `head` which has not been updated. This can easily explain the behaviour you are seeing, by starting the iteration halfway through the list.

More importantly this does not seem to be an implementation of insertion sort to me. Insertion sort is done by inserting into an already sorted list at the correct point. So would look like:

```
sortedList Sort(unsortedlist):
   sortedList = []
   foreach item in unsortedlist:
     sortedList.InsertAtTheRighPlace(item)
   return sortedList
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your direction, bro.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So the code fragment below **Here is my code for Insertion Sort** is making some serious workarounds that I guess even you won't be able to properly imagine :).

Try breaking your problem into simpler steps, **How would you have gone to implement a LinkedList where you could just add an Integer(Anything really, just the OOP complexity varies) in Ascending or Descending form**. The following code that I just **tested** would help you atleast see how you should have implemented a **LinkedList that grows via InsertionSort algo** , note that this is dealing the **ascending order case**

```
public class LinkedList
{

    public Node first , last;

    public class Node
    {
        public int data;

        public Node next;

        public Node( int data )
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public void addInsertSort( int num )
    {
        if( isEmpty() )
        {
            first = new Node( num );
            last = first;
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node( num );
            Node curNode = first , preNode = null;
            while( curNode != null && newNode.data > curNode.data )
            {
                preNode = curNode;
                curNode = curNode.next;
            }
            if( curNode == first )
            {
                newNode.next = first;
                first = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                if( curNode != null && preNode != null ) //middle of list
                {
                    newNode.next = curNode;
                    preNode.next = newNode;
                }
                else if( curNode == null ) // end of list
                {
                    preNode.next = newNode;
                    last = newNode; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return first == null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "[";
        for( Node curNode = first; curNode != null; curNode = curNode.next )
        {
            str += curNode.data + " ";
        }
        return str + "]";
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

        list.addInsertSort( 4 );
        list.addInsertSort( 5 );
        list.addInsertSort( 1 );
        list.addInsertSort( 6 );
        list.addInsertSort( 10 );
        list.addInsertSort( 0 );

        System.out.println( list );
    }

}
```

Im sorry, the code editor here is REALLY KILLING ME, please don't mind the frequent re-edits

Now going on with how you would integrate this idea in your methods, you can fix things like this, and make sure it looks exactly this way

```
// You really dont need more variables in your LinkedList class
// Both of these are enough, forget currentNode reference
public Node head , last;

public void initializeLL(){
    try
    {
        File file = new File("Asg2Data.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            Data d = new Data(sc.next(), sc.nextInt());
            Node n = new Node(d);

            addInsertSort( n );
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public Node addInsertSort( Node newNode )
{
    if( isEmpty() )
    {
        head = newNode;
        last = head;
    }
    else
    {
        Node curNode = head , preNode = null;
        // This is How InsertionSort would have gone to search the list
        while( curNode != null && newNode.getData().getNum() > curNode.getData().getNum() )
        {
            preNode = curNode;
            curNode = curNode.next;
        }
        //Thats the happy ending of the insertionSort algo
        //Now we need to link newNode with OUR DYNAMICALLY GROWING LIST
        //When the insertion Algo stopped, It told us where the newNode 
        //shall be placed in comparison to the current state of list

        // Is this supposed to be the head node now??
        if( curNode == head )
        {
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else // maybe we landed BETWEEN the list or at the END OF LIST??
        {
            if( curNode != null && preNode != null ) //BETWEEN THE list
            {
                newNode.next = curNode;
                preNode.next = newNode;
            }
            else if( curNode == null ) // end of list
            {
                preNode.next = newNode;
                last = newNode; 
            }
        }
    }
    return newNode; 
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return head == null;
}
```

Let me know if something still goes wrong, I will explain more deeply

Comment: Awesomeeeeee. My program worked perfectly. Thanks So much.

Comment: Thanks so much, bro. My program worked perfectly now.